# Android- YouTube IFrame API: Unable to play HD videos

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using YouTube Iframe API so that I can play videos as desirable quality but I'm not able to play HD video even if I take player size as recommended.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en#Playback_quality

On some devices HD videos are also playing like Galaxy S5, Xperia etc. But Galaxy s6, Nexus5 etc devices are not able to play HD videos. Normal videos like upto 480p all devices are playing.

The api says that we have to change player size accordingly to what quality of video is playing.

**So, how YouTube application is playing without changing player size even HD videos??**

Here is some code of Iframe what I'm using:

```
 var tag = document.createElement('script');

 tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
 var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player',
     {
     height: '180',  // Changing height/width for HD videos.
     width: '320',    
     playervars: 
      {
        'fs': 0, 
        'controls': 1, 
        'disablekb':1, 
        'enablejsapi': 1,
        'iv_load_policy':3, 
        'playsinline': 1, 
        'rel': 0,
        'hd': 1, // Deprecated now
        'vq': hd720, // Not working (Not added to api)
        'showinfo':0
      },          
    });

  }

 function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.cueVideoById("WPvGqX-TXP0", 0, "hd720");
  }
```

For HD videos I increase the player size (height/width) but it doesn't take any effect. for 720p (1280px by 720px) and for 1080p (1920px by 1080px ).

Somewhere I read adding the parameters ('hd: 1' or 'vq: hd720') to the player do affect for hd video but 'hd' is deprecated now and 'vq' is not added to Iframe api.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5#Parameters

**what should I do to play HD video properly?? Is it also possible to play video like YouTube application at fixed/small player size??**

Comment: bhaiya e na ho payi....

Comment: @AtulBhardwaj: I did it :-)

Comment: @Hulk can you tell how?

Comment: @Chordin4tion: you need to make adjustable player size according to video quality. If the data rate is low then it would automatically degrade the quality as well.

Comment: @Hulk Thanks for the info...I figured it out myself...There is a bug in Youtube iFrame API which restrict android users to play videos on 480p+...So I changed the userAgent in the webView properties to iPhone and it's working great now...

Comment: @Chordin4tion: what about changing in user agent in the webview to Android? is it not working?

Comment: @Hulk It's working perfectly...

Comment: @Chordin4tion: you mean without changing player size? if it is then please explain what did you set the user agent to play hd videos?

Comment: set it to "iphone", but remember if you set video playback quality to auto it will not play HD videos on low end devices...as per my observations on Nexus 5 Auto plays videos at max 480p quality...while playing a video in Galaxy S6 with Auto selected can go upto 720p in portrait orientation...

Comment: @Chordin4tion: Can you tell what to set for HD quality(not auto) on Android device?

Comment: @Hulk Set userAgent to "iphone" and then call setPlaybackQuality() method to set playback quality to your desired resolution...